# Add icon to SBSearchTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

I am trying to add an icon to a SBSearchTableViewCell.

I was adding a subview on top of the cell but that still left a border, and the text was underneath the icon.

http://i.imgur.com/tGqWaEa.png

I tried hooking into `-[SBSearchModel _imageForDomain:andDisplayID:]` but the domain is 0 and the displayID is (null).

Code: http://pastebin.ca/2460380

Resources:

- http://theiostream.tumblr.com/post/54339870761/hacking-the-ios-spotlight-v2
- https://github.com/theiostream/SearchLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set image using `-(void)setTitleImage:(id)image animated:(BOOL)animated;` method (I'm not sure what it does, but that is the only method to set image in the cell you are using...)? And, How about just creating your own labels, and place them on the right places? That should not be that hard, I think. Good Luck!

**EDIT**
Sorry it seems like the method I mentioned is available only on iOS 7 and higher. I suggest you to use you own `UILabel`s and `UIImageView` with imitation to the original.

**ANOTHER EDIT**
It looks like the `SBSearchTableViewCell` is the subclass of the `UITableViewCell`, so why don't you use the it's `imageView` property to set the image (or, icon) to the cell?

Comment: Setting the imageView still leaves the border on the side and the icon covering the title.

Comment: The title is drawn on the cell

Comment: Did you try to use the built-in `imageView` property of the cell as I suggested on the last edit? How about your own `UILabel`s and `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the border over by setting `cell.sectionHeaderWidth`. Then you can add a subview like you already have done.